# A VPN Server On Router Versus A Conventional Computer?

Tags: vpn, router

So we have an OpenVPN Server running on a Synology File Server. We have SSH into the Synology to have custom certificate keys and a password for two factor authentication.

This is working well, and allows us to access the network remotely for files, printers etc. We are happy, BUT I noticed our router which is a Netgear Nighthawk has an OpenVPN server built into it with it's own client certificate ready to download etc.

This got me wondering, are VPNs better or more secure running on the router itself versus a machine on the network? If you run a VPN on a machine even a Synology machine you run the risk of the machine turning off. Also, is it faster to have a VPN on the router itself to access the rest of the network versus a machine on the network, or are the speed differences negligible?

I've many times used Softether VPN for other network access which I like more, but unless the router has Open WRT I end up having to use a machine on the network running Softether. Does this matter?

I know that a router is technically a computer, but you guys get my point.  I'm wondering if something like a raspberry pi would also be better or an option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using VPN on a router more secure than using a dedicated VPN machine?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77189/is-using-vpn-on-a-router-more-secure-than-using-a-dedicated-vpn-machine)

Comment: arm before v8 does not support hardware crypto, to my knowledge. This may have a performance impact compared to an x86 desktop or server with AES-NI. But I am not aware of the impact in practice.

Comment: Multithr this would be on a newer Nighthawk router so I'm sure it has that. That said, you're saying it really doesn't make much difference in practice for LAN access? The router mind you only uses an OpenVPN certificate akin to that router, but not double authentication via a password. In my mind that doesn't matter that much, as a certificate is extremely hard to brute force etc. Unless someone has a certificate that shouldn't which is unlikely to happen in our case since we aren't giving them to employees.